# How to read files asynchroneusly in c++?

Tags: c++, winapi, asynchronous

I need to read file asynchroneously

```
string read(string path) {
            DWORD readenByte;
            int t;
            char* buffer = new char[512];
            HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, "read");
            OVERLAPPED overlap;
            overlap.hEvent = hEvent;
            HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(path.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
            if(!hFile) {
                Debug::error(GetLastError(), "fileAsync.cpp::read - ");
            }
            t = ReadFile(hFile, buffer, MAX_READ - 1, &readenByte, &overlap);
            if(!t) {
                Debug::error(GetLastError(), "fileAsync.cpp::read - ");
            }
            t = WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, 5000);
            if(t == WAIT_TIMEOUT) {
                Debug::error("fail to read - timeout, fileAsync.cpp::read");
            }
            buffer[readenByte] = '\0';
            string str = buffer;
            return str;
        }
```

I've got the error at ReadFile - 38: reached the end of the file

How to read asynchroneusly file in c++ with use of winapi?

Comment: Your error message is in the end of file detection [example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365690.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several bugs in your code that need to be addressed, some cause failure, others catastrophic failure.

- The first bug leads to the error code you get: You have an uninitialized [OVERLAPPED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684342.aspx) structure, instructing the following `ReadFile` call to read from the random file position stored in the *Offset* and *OffsetHigh* members. To fix this, initialize the data: `OVERLAPPED overlap = {0};`.
- Next, you aren't opening the file for asynchronous access. To subsequently read asynchronously from a file, you need to call [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) passing `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` for *dwFlagsAndAttributes*. If you don't you're off to hunting a bug for months (see [What happens if you forget to pass an OVERLAPPED structure on an asynchronous handle?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121012-00/?p=6343)).
- The documentation for [ReadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467.aspx) explains, that *lpNumberOfBytesRead* parameter is not used for asynchronous I/O, and you should pass `NULL` instead. This should be immediately obvious, since an asynchronous `ReadFile` call returns, before the number of bytes transferred is known. To get the size of the transferred payload, call [GetOverlappedResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683209.aspx) once the asynchronous I/O has finished.
- The next bug only causes a memory leak. You are dynamically allocating `buffer`, but never call `delete[] buffer;`. Either delete the buffer, or allocate a buffer with automatic storage duration (`char buffer[MAX_READ] = {0};`), or use a C++ container (e.g. `std::vector<char> buffer(MAX_READ);`).
- Another bug is, where you try to construct a `std::string` from your `buffer`: The constructor you chose cannot deal with what would be an embedded `NUL` character. It'll just truncate whatever you have. You'd need to call a [std::string constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) taking an explicit length argument. But even then, you may wind up with garbage, if the character encoding of the file and `std::string` do not agree.
- Finally, issuing an asynchronous read, followed by `WaitForSingleObject` is essentially a synchronous read, and doesn't buy you anything. I'm assuming this is just for testing, and not your final code. Just keep in mind when finishing this up, that the `OVERLAPPED` structure need to stay alive for as long as the asynchronous read operation is in flight.

Additional recommendations, that do not immediately address bugs:

- You are passing a `std::string` to your `read` function, that is used in the `CreateFile` call. Windows uses UTF-16LE encoding throughout, which maps to `wchar_t`/`std::wstring` when using Visual Studio (and likely other Windows compilers as well). Passing a `std::string`/`const char*` has two immediate drawbacks:

  1. Calling the ANSI API causes character strings to be converted from MBCS to UTF-16 (and vice versa). This both needlessly wastes resources, as well as fails in very subtle ways, as it relies on the current locale.
  2. Not every Unicode code point can be expressed using MBCS encoding. This means, that some files cannot be opened when using MBCS character encoding.

  Use the Unicode API (`CreateFileW`) and UTF-16 character strings (`std::wstring`/`wchar_t`) throughout. You can also define the preprocessor symbols `UNICODE` (for the Windows API) and `_UNICODE` (for the CRT) at the compiler's command line, to not accidentally call into any ANSI APIs.
- You are creating an event object that is only ever accessed through its `HANDLE` value, not by its name. You can pass `NULL` as the *lpName* argument to [CreateEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396.aspx). This prevents potential name clashes, which is all the more important with a name as generic as `"read"`.

Comment: One more bug. After use is obvious to call CloseHandle(hFile) to free resource. If forget, it impossible to use CreateFile again with the same file.

Comment: @Nikita: Even if you forget to close the handle, you can still open it, as long as you use compatible access and share mode. But that's not unusual, the same restrictions apply the first time you open a handle. You should still close the handle when you're done to not leak resources, and to remove potential access or sharing restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

1) You need to include the flag `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` in the 6th argument (`dwFlagsAndAttributes`) of the call to [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx). That is why most likely the overlapped read fails.

2) What is the value of `MAX_READ`? I hope it's less than 513 otherwise if the file is bigger than 512 bytes bad things will happen.

3) `ReadFile` with the overlapped structure pointer being not `NULL` will give you the error code 997 (`ERROR_IO_PENDING`) which is expected and thus you cannot evaluate the `t` after calling `ReadFile`.

4) In the case of asynchronous operation the `ReadFile` function does not store the bytes read in the pointer you pass in the call, you must query the overlapped result yourself after the operation is completed.

Here is a small working snippet, I hope you can build up from that:

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class COverlappedCompletionEvent : public OVERLAPPED
{
public:
    COverlappedCompletionEvent() : m_hEvent(NULL)
    {
        m_hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
        if (m_hEvent == NULL)
        {
            auto nError = GetLastError();
            std::stringstream ErrorStream;
            ErrorStream << "CreateEvent() failed with " << nError;
            throw std::runtime_error(ErrorStream.str());
        }
        ZeroMemory(this, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
        hEvent = m_hEvent;
    }
    ~COverlappedCompletionEvent()
    {
        if (m_hEvent != NULL)
        {
            CloseHandle(m_hEvent);
        }
    }

private:
    HANDLE m_hEvent;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        if (argc != 2)
        {
            std::stringstream ErrorStream;
            ErrorStream << "usage: " << argv[0] << " <filename>";
            throw std::runtime_error(ErrorStream.str());
        }
        COverlappedCompletionEvent OverlappedCompletionEvent;
        char pBuffer[512];
        auto hFile = CreateFileA(argv[1], GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
        if (hFile == NULL)
        {
            auto nError = GetLastError();
            std::stringstream ErrorStream;
            ErrorStream << "CreateFileA() failed with " << nError;
            throw std::runtime_error(ErrorStream.str());
        }
        if (ReadFile(hFile, pBuffer, sizeof(pBuffer), nullptr, &OverlappedCompletionEvent) == FALSE)
        {
            auto nError = GetLastError();
            if (nError != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
            {
                std::stringstream ErrorStream;
                ErrorStream << "ReadFile() failed with " << nError;
                throw std::runtime_error(ErrorStream.str());
            }
        }
        ::WaitForSingleObject(OverlappedCompletionEvent.hEvent, INFINITE);
        DWORD nBytesRead = 0;
        if (GetOverlappedResult(hFile, &OverlappedCompletionEvent, &nBytesRead, FALSE))
        {
            std::cout << "Read " << nBytesRead << " bytes" << std::endl;
        }
        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& Exception)
    {
        std::cout << Exception.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: All your calls to `GetLastError` happen too late. `GetLastError` must be called **immediately** after the predicate for when to call it has become true. Interspersed constructors and stream operators can set a different error code, leading to meaningless, red-herring-type error logs.

Comment: @IInspectable noted and fixed.

Comment: Not quite. There may be (invisible) code in between your call to `CreateEvent` and entering the c'tor. You'd have to move the call to `CreateEvent` into the c'tor body.

Comment: @IInspectable since I don't have any other member variables whose initialization might call some WinAPI stuff and the base c'tor has already been called, can you provide any example of a code that could set a false error?

Comment: You are relying on implementation details. There is no documented contract that says, that Visual Studio (or any other compiler) will not emit any code in between a class' c'tor's initializer list and the c'tor body. There could very well be stack balancing code inserted, for diagnostics, or anything else, including no code. But there is no guarantee for that.

Comment: @IInspectable meh, that breaks the beauty of initializer lists but ok.